# How can I write this as a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I have the following code snippet embedded into some of my divs so when those divs get clicked a certain radio button gets checked.

```
onclick="document.g1.city[0].checked=true;"
```

However I would like to convert the above call to a function call like below:

```
onclick="checkRadioButton(city[0]);"
```

And the function will be something like this

```
function checkRadioButton(input){
    document.g1.input.checked=true;
}
```

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Is it possible to put "var" in the functions arguments? o_o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write any Javascript code inside the `onclick` attribute. Remember that `city[0]` is not defined anywhere. To access it, you must specify the full `document.g1.city[0]`. So the onclick becomes:

```
onclick="checkRadioButton(document.g1.city[0]);"
```

Inside your function, you are already receiving the element, and don't have to retrieve it from the document again. You could directly set it's `checked` property:

```
function checkRadioButton(input) {
   input.checked = true;
}
```

Comment: You need to remove the `var` keyword on the function argument list.

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="checkRadioButton(document.g1.city[0]);"

checkRadioButton(var input){
    input.checked=true;
}
```

You can also reduce the need for supplying `document.g1.city[0]` if, for example, every `DIV` that you mark thusly has an attribute "radioID", and the value of the attribute must match the ID given to the radio button:

```
onclick="checkRadioButton(this);"

checkRadioButton(var div){
    document.getElementById(div.radioID).checked=true;
}
```

Comment: In xhtml I'm supposed to use every id only once on every page right? So won't this code require invalid xhtml where multiple elements will have the same id which is `radioID`:  "document.getElementById(div.radioID).checked=true;"